# Visual jQuery for jQuery 1.3.2

Tags: jquery

[Visual jQuery](http://visualjquery.com/) website, which is originally created by Yehuda Katz & updated by Remy Sharp, is very helpful & interactive to explore jQuery API. I'm using this website a lot more than [jQuery documentation website](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)

I'm still waiting for someone to update the website since it still demonstrate jQuery 1.2.6. Anyone you know some website similar to this for jQuery 1.3.2 or jQuery UI ?

Comment: For the person that voted to close- I don't think that this is spam.

Comment: I LOVE those visual API docs! Is there a list of all known available visual API docs somewhere? I just know one more: The German http://visualselfhtml.org/ for HTML, CSS, XML, JavaScript and Perl.

Comment: Found another visual API for HTML, CSS, JS: http://www.gotapi.com/html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Remy Sharp](http://remysharp.com/) answered this question by [his tweet](http://twitter.com/rem/status/5362040739).

[visual.jquery.com](http://visual.jquery.com/) is the new [visualjquery.com](http://visualjquery.com/)

**update**: the site moved (again) to [jqapi.com](http://jqapi.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Another one with updated API jQuery 1.6

[www.visualjquery.net](http://www.visualjquery.net)

http://jqapi.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think Visual jQuery got rolled into Aptana Studio - so check out http://www.aptana.com/

Comment: hmh.. I don't understand. That is IDE for Ruby on Rails.

Comment: It's not just for Ruby on Rails - it works for loads of languages.

Answer (score 1):

Also, check this out:

**jQuery Deconstructed**

http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/deconstructed/jquery/

> The Deconstructed series is designed to visually and interactively deconstruct the internal code of JavaScript libraries, including jQuery, Prototype and MooTools.
>
> It breaks the physical JavaScript into visual blocks that you can easiliy navigate. Each block opens to reveal its internal code. Clickable hyperlinks allow you to follow program flow.

A new way to look at the internals of jQuery!

Comment: that IS unique, but looking at it does give me a headache

Answer (score 0):

this is the Visual jQuery for jQuery 1.3.2 version
http://nexsis.cl/visualjquery/

this version of visual api is very good for those who begin with jquery.

Origin: https://github.com/jquery-archive/visual-jquery