# Documentation for the DOM, JavaScript & CSS

Tags: javascript, css, dom

What's the best place to find full documentation for the DOM, JavaScript, and CSS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best resources to learn JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript)

Comment: The Mozilla Development Center is quite good: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: Adding "mdc" to your searches usually gets you the Mozilla Development Center article on the topic. I almost always add this to my searches.

Comment: This should be helpful: [W3 Viewer](http://w3viewer.com)

Comment: old topic only metion javascript

Answer (score 3):

There are many reasons why there isn't just one site that displays every single JavaScript method or function, every DOM manipulative option, or every CSS property. The main reason being that there are multiple browsers with which have different engines.

Most popular engines being used today are: 
**Trident**, **Gecko**, **Webkit**, and **Presto**.

JavaScript and CSS are an "always-in-progress" project, so finding all the available api's might be a little hard to find. Though, there *are* resources out there to help you with particular browsers.

I find these pretty helpful:

- ### MDN Doc Center (Gecko)

  - Good for a general use case for just about any browser, though they do provide more info on their specific properties, such as `-mos` (Gecko) in CSS.
  - HTML Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element
  - JavaScript Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference
  - CSS Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS
  - DOM Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference
  - Most popular browsers using the Trident engine: Firefox, Camino, Flock, Seamonkey, Epiphany, Netscape
- ### Webkit

  - One of my favorite engines to work with! It's what powers Safari and what Chrom is based off.
  - DOM: [https://developer.apple.com/...riJSProgTopics/WebKitJavaScript.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/WebKitJavaScript.html)
  - HTML: [https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/.../SafariHTMLRef](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002049)
  - CSS: [https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/.../SafariCSSRef](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002050)
  - Most popular browsers using the WebKit engine: Safari, Google Chrome, Epiphany, Konqueror
- ### Opera Specs (Presto)

  - Not the most helpful thing in the world, but gives you a good idea of what the presto engine currently supports
  - Link: http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/productspecs/
  - Most popular browsers using the Presto engine: Opera Desktop/Mobile/Mini, Nintendo DS, Wii Internet Channel
- ### MSDN (for Trident<sup>?</sup>)

  - I rarely design just for Internet Explorer anymore (if at all), but this does look a little promising:
  - Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155073.aspx
  - Most popular browsers using the Trident engine: Internet Explorer, Avant Browser, Maxathon, AOL Browser

---

If all else fails, refer to W3 (and I don't mean W3 Schools; the two aren't event affiliated):

- CSS: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/
- DOM: http://www.w3.org/DOM/

ECMAScript (where JavaScript derives from) has an official PDF for specifications as well:

- JavaScript: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf

Comment: This is a good list. I would consider posting it in [the original](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript). (This question is a duplicate many times over.)

Comment: @Pekka: If this question is closed, I'll consider rewriting this just  a little and post it there as well. :)

Comment: Autosuggest search based API documentations for JS, jQuery, HTML, CSS are really handy to find things fast: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660707/visual-jquery-for-jquery-1-3-2