# Add html to div without replacing the current content in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml

I'm trying to add dhtml to the div with the id upload_results. That should work without replacing the current content in the div.

The Code: (interesting part is at the bottom)

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 function do_show() {
      $("#webcamContainer").fadeIn('');
  }

  webcam.set_hook( 'onComplete', 'my_completion_handler' );

  function do_upload() {
       upload to server
      document.getElementById('upload_results').innerHTML = '<div>Uploading...</div>';
      webcam.upload();
  }

  function my_completion_handler(msg) {
       extract URL out of PHP output
      if (msg.match(/(http\:\/\/\S+)/)) {
          var image_url = RegExp.$1;
           show JPEG image in page
          $("#upload_results").fadeIn('');
          //document.getElementById('upload_results').innerHTML = '<a target="_blank" href="'+image_url+'"><img style="border:#ccc 5px solid;" src="'+image_url+'" width="100px"></a>';// I think here should be something changed
    $('#upload_results').append('<a target="_blank" href="'+image_url+'"><img style="border:#ccc 5px solid;" src="'+image_url+'" width="100px"></a>');      
           reset camera for another shot
          webcam.reset();
      }
      else alert("PHP Error: " + msg);
  }
 </script>


 <div id="upload_results" class="video_header" style="display:none;"></div><!--add data here , without replace current content in div-->
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing `//` for single line commenting - that would cause the code to not work.

Comment: use one of those websites to quickly find the stuff from the jquery API u need.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660707/visual-jquery-for-jquery-1-3-2 that stuff falls under category manipulation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) content to the `#upload_results` element:

```
$('#upload_results').append('<a target="_blank" href="'+image_url+'"><img style="border:#ccc 5px solid;" src="'+image_url+'" width="100px"></a>');
```

You could also use `.innerHTML += '[...]';` but that's usually considered bad practice as it overwrites existing DOM, trashing out existing listeners and data previously attached to the elements.

Comment: I think its the same like INNER HTML, I tried it and the same function, so it didn't work

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing else interfering with the code? I'll post a full example if needed.

Comment: @HamadaBadran Your `do_upload` function overwrites the inner HTML emptying the `upload_results` element. Any `document.getElementById('upload_results').innerHTML =` in your code will overwrite the contents, apart from that I don't see anything that could be going wrong.

Comment: I am using a WebCam JavaScript Tool to take snaps and I want to show all photos taken...

Comment: I thought so. It's hard to debug without a live example though. Check if there isn't anything else writing to `upload_results` e.g. comment out your loading message temporarily and check again. `.append()` will never overwrite existing contents.

Answer (score 7):

check out: `insertAdjacentHTML` method:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.insertAdjacentHTML